# Does Mozilla Prism allow me to build an application bundle that I can upload to the App Store?

Tags: web-applications, mozilla-prism

Does Mozilla Prism allow me to build an OSX application bundle that I can upload to the Mac App Store?

Does Mozilla Prism allow me to build an OSX application bundle that I can give to another user who does not and will not have prism installed?

Does Mozilla Prism allow me to build an Windows application that I can package with an installer?

Does Mozilla Prism allow the application to run disconnected from the network assuming that non of my .html/.js requires access to the network.

My goal is to take my very simple and self contained .html and .js files and build an application that I can give to users and not expect them to install any other software or be connected to the network.

Currently I am using adobe air to do this.  I am successful, but I would like make delivering the app more mainstream.

By mainstream I mean:
1) for OSX: drag to the application fold to installed.
2) for windows: use a traditional wizard based install.